# Opensource CMS that allows defining editable regions

Tags: php, mysql, css, open-source, content-management-system

I'm looking for an **opensource** lightweight CMS for those situations where you would like to be able to set up a web site with some **editable content regions**, but don’t want to have to install a full-blown CMS or try to hack a blogging system in order to do the job. Something similar to Perch or Cushy CMS, but free and opensource ofcourse.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried having a look at concrete CMS.

Has editable regions and is fairly easy to use.

http://www.concrete5.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://php.opensourcecms.com/ they have a **lot** of CMSs (all opensource), they all have demos or links to demos. Check out the lite categories and you should be able to find what you want.